# Left join on substring compared with number in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am using Oracle 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 and I want to left join two tables on a substring of one of the columns. (see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8955c8/8 for example)

Table 1 is `DW_PCS`:

```
DESC DW_PCS

Result:
PAYEE_ID      VARCHAR2
ACCOUNT_NB    VARCHAR2
```

Table 2 is `DW_CLAIM`:

```
DESC DW_CLAIM

Result:
CLAIM_ID      VARCHAR2
CLAIMANT_ID   NUMBER
```

`SUBSTR(DW_PCS.PAYEE_ID, 2, 7)` is an alias for `CLAIMANT_ID`, so I tried the following which works fine in MySQL (see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8955c8/8):

```
SELECT 
  DW_PCS.PAYEE_ID, 
  SUBSTR(DW_PCS.PAYEE_ID, 2, 7) AS CLAIMANT_ID, 
  DW_PCS.ACCOUNT_NB,
  DW_CLAIM.CLAIM_ID 
FROM 
  DW_PCS 
  LEFT JOIN DWH.DW_CLAIM ON 
  SUBSTR(DW_PCS.PAYEE_ID, 2, 7) = DW_CLAIM.CLAIMANT_ID
```

But this throws ORA-12801/ORA-01722 error which apparently means that I am not using the correct data types in my comparison.

Now, if I change the condition to `SUBSTR(DW_PCS.PAYEE_ID, 2, 7) = TO_CHAR(DW_CLAIM.CLAIMANT_ID)`, it works unless the `PAYEE_ID` is something like `C0152426`. The leading zeros become problematic because of `DW_CLAIM.CLAIMANT_ID` is a number. How should I make this query in Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you have some "corrupt" data, where `SUBSTR(d.PAYEE_ID, 2, 7)` isn't numeric. You can identify these using REGEXP_LIKE for example: `WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(SUBSTR(d.PAYEE_ID, 2, 7), '\D')`.

Then it is your choice how to proceed with this data. One possibility is to use case in the JOIN condition and only JOIN when SUBSTR(d.PAYEE_ID, 2, 7) is numeric:

```
SELECT
    d.PAYEE_ID,
    SUBSTR(d.PAYEE_ID, 2, 7) AS CLAIMANT_ID,
    d.ACCOUNT_NB,
    c.CLAIM_ID
FROM DW_PCS d
LEFT JOIN DW_CLAIM c
  ON c.CLAIMANT_ID = CASE WHEN NOT REGEXP_LIKE(SUBSTR(d.PAYEE_ID, 2, 7),'\D') 
                          THEN TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(d.PAYEE_ID, 2, 7))
                     END
```

P.S.: I think MySQL transforms both sides to strings for the comparison whereas Oracle tries to transform the left side to a number which results in this error. Therefore the difference...

Comment: Yes, you are right. I had corrupt data. Using REGEXP_LIKE, I found the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the `PAYEE_ID` substring to a number:

```
SELECT
    d.PAYEE_ID,
    SUBSTR(d.PAYEE_ID, 2) AS CLAIMANT_ID,
    d.ACCOUNT_NB,
    dc.CLAIM_ID
FROM DW_PCS d
LEFT JOIN DWH.DW_CLAIM dc
    ON TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(d.PAYEE_ID, 2)) = c.CLAIMANT_ID;
```

Using this approach, both sides of the `ON` comparison would be numbers, thereby avoiding the leading zero problem.

Comment: I have tried it before. But it throws ORA-12801/ORA-01722 and it doesn't make sense to me why

Comment: Please setup a demo fiddle in Oracle using my query, to show that it really does not work (it should, from what I can see here).

Answer (score 0):

> this throws []`ORA-01722` error which apparently means that I am not using the correct data types in my comparison.

No, `ORA-01722` is an Invalid Number error. This means that Oracle is implicitly trying to convert the values to the same data type and is converting `SUBSTR(DW_PCS.PAYEE_ID, 2, 7)` to a number but at least one of the rows has non-numeric values in that substring and the conversion fails.

If this is not to be expected then you need to fix your data - you can find the offending rows using:

```
SELECT *
FROM   DW_PCS
WHERE  NOT REGEXP_LIKE( SUBSTR(PAYEE_ID, 2, 7), '^\d+$' )
```

> The leading zeros become problematic because of DW_CLAIM.CLAIMANT_ID is a number. How should I make this query in Oracle?

You can solve your problem by zero-padding the start of the `CLAIMANT_ID` when you convert it to a string:

```
SELECT 
  DW_PCS.PAYEE_ID, 
  SUBSTR(DW_PCS.PAYEE_ID, 2, 7) AS CLAIMANT_ID, 
  DW_PCS.ACCOUNT_NB,
  DW_CLAIM.CLAIM_ID 
FROM 
  DW_PCS 
  LEFT JOIN DWH.DW_CLAIM ON 
  SUBSTR(DW_PCS.PAYEE_ID, 2, 7) = TO_CHAR( DW_CLAIM.CLAIMANT_ID, 'fm0000000' )
```